# Can someone help me with this proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

Prove that, for any integer $n$, if $n-2$ is divisible by $4$,then $n^2-4$ is divisible by $16$.

*I don't know what kind of method to use.

Comment: Take a look at our pointers for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with particular emphasis on [avoiding "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: If $n-2$ is divisible by $4$, then so is $n+2$. The result follows since $n^2-4=(n+2)(n-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$n^2-4=(n-2)(n-2+4)=(n-2)^2+4(n-2)$$

Comment: Can i ask what kind of method should i use? Cuz i had no idea.

Comment: @ITstudent, Could you follow the steps here. For example, if  4 divides $n-2,4^2$ will divide $$(n-2)^2$$

Comment: @ITstudent "*what kind of method should I use?*"  Direct algebraic manipulation where the final step involves factoring a common factor of $16$ from everything, proving that the resulting expression after rearrangement is a multiple of $16$.

Answer (score 1):

You are told that $n-2$ is divisible by $4$, which means that there exists an integer $k$ such that $n-2=4k$.

And now it's easy:

$n-2=4k\implies n=4k+2\implies n^2-4=(4k+2)^2-4=\ldots$ what?